# Find a particular automorphism

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, automorphism-group

Let $\Omega$ be $(\mathbb{R}^-\cup{0})^c$. Find an automorphism that has $1$ as a fixed point and it is not the identity.

Could an inversion of the plane across the $xy$ axis be an automorphism that satisfies the condition? Since the set seems to be the upper left quadrant I'm thinking of having the function defined as $\phi (z)=1/z$.

Comment: your set does not seem to be the upper left quadrant, but (if I understand correctly?) the complement of the negative real axis. Also probably you don't want to have 0 in your domain otherwise it's not open

Comment: An automorphism in what sense?

Comment: @Mr.Chip I guess a biholomorphism

Comment: @Mr.Chip Gloubloubarbaki is right.

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki but $\phi(z)=1/z$ does not have a zero, does it work? And I think only $1$ is fixed for $\phi$

Comment: $\phi$ would work if $0$ were not included in $\Omega$, but it is...

Comment: @Mr.Chip Set $\phi (0)=0$ then?

Comment: That's going to fail continuity.

Comment: @Mr.Chip ok... $\phi(z)=z^2$ satisfies continuity, and has $-$ as a fixed point, and is not the identity

Comment: @Cure Like I said, I think there is a typo in your domain. I think it should be $\mathbb C \backslash \mathbb R^-$, since otherwise your domain is not open. And in that case, $\phi(z)=1/z$ does work

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki You're right, there was a mistake. I fixed it now.